# email duplicate check php with Database

Tags: php, mysql

I've got small problem checking the duplicate email, i dont know what ive done wrong. I could get the typed email address from previous page through POST but query1 is not readed($sql1). So if i echo $reg_num, it always appear '0' even though It's working on mysql workbench. I tried a lot of things like echo $emailAddress before $sql1, or echo $reg_num.... Please help me tho..

```
if(strpos($emailAddress, $emailValidCheck) === false) { 
    echo "<script> alert('Invalid email type. Use the correct email address.'); history.back(); </script>";
}

else {
    echo $emailAddress;

    $sql1="SELECT count(*) as count FROM peekachews.tbl_user WHERE user_email=".$emailAddress."";
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);  
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); 
    $reg_num=$row1['count'];   

    if($reg_num > 0)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Duplicated email.'); history.back(); </script>";
        die;
    }

    else if($reg_num = 0) {
        $sql2="insert into tbl_user (user_firstName, user_lastName, user_email, user_password, user_date) ";
        $sql2.="values ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$emailAddress', '$password', now() )";
        $result2=mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        //tot_row=mysql_affected_rows();
        mysqli_close($conn);

        echo "<script> alert('Congratulations on becoming a Peeknchews registered member.');
        location.replace('../php_login/login.php'); </script>";   
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, try to add quotes to user_email value, like user_email = '".$emailAddress."';";

Answer (score 0):

You should be using parameters instead of just sticking `$emailaddress` into the `$sql1` string.

If you don't want to use parameters, you just need to put quotes in the `$sql1` string around the email address like this:

```
$sql1="SELECT count(*) as count FROM peekachews.tbl_user WHERE user_email='$emailAddress'";
```

Comment: You could also make the user_email column unique. Then instead of querying for an existing email, you just try the insert and if it fails you parse the error message to see if it was because of a duplicate email.

Comment: Solved. thanks. But I always use variable in sql sentences like this.==>   '.$variable.'
But i don't know why dots are input in sql haha anyway thank you very much ! have a good one!

Comment: You really should switch to using parameters. Your code will be much more secure.

Comment: Thanks for advising me. But I wanna know more about the switch to using parameters. I really wanna use that for ma secure but How can i switch?
Thanks,D

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I don't know why dot(.) is input in sql sentence but totally sql was wrong.

Correcting

```
$sql1="SELECT count(*) as count FROM peekachews.tbl_user WHERE user_email='$emailAddress'";
```